# Mutual SSL enabled API call is not happening via postman in WSO2 API Manager 4.1.0 GA Release

Tags: ssl, wso2, wso2-api-manager, keytool, mutual-authentication

I am trying [Mutual SSL](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-security/api-authentication/secure-apis-using-mutual-ssl/) in WSO2 APIM 4.1.0 GA Release. I have created `Self signed certificate` by using `Java Keytool`.

**OS :** Windows 11

**Below are the commands to generate certificate:**

**Creating new Keystore:**

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias dev.wso2.com -keystore "C:\pathtoAPIM\wso2am-4.1.0\repository\resources\security\devwso2.jks" -validity 4000
```

**Convert to pkcs12 format:**

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore C:\pathtoAPIM\wso2am-4.1.0\repository\resources\security\devwso2.jks -destkeystore C:\pathtoAPIM\wso2am-4.1.0\repository\resources\security\devwso2.jks -deststoretype pkcs12
```

**Export public key**

```
keytool -exportcert -alias dev.wso2.com -rfc -file "C:\pathtoAPIM\wso2am-4.1.0\repository\resources\security\devwso2.pem" -keystore "C:\pathtoAPIM\wso2am-4.1.0\repository\resources\security\devwso2.jks"
```

**import the public key to trust store:**

```
keytool -import -alias dev.wso2.com -file "C:\pathtoAPIM\wso2am-4.1.0\repository\resources\security\devwso2.pem" -keystore "C:\pathtoAPIM\wso2am-4.1.0\repository\resources\security\client-truststore.jks"
```

- Certificate added successfully into truststore and validated certificate from management console too.

[image: certificate]

- Created API in Publisher portal and enabled `Mutual SSL` as mandatory

[image: mutual ssl enabled]

- upload a new client certificate and marking OAuth as optional under `Application level security`

[image: certificate added]

- API is published into devportal.

**Invoke an API secured with Mutual SSL using Postman**

- Added the certificate and private key in Certificate tab of Postman settings.
  **Host:** `dev.wso2.com`
  **CRT file:** `dev.wso2.crt`
  **KEY file:** `devwso2.pem`
  **Passphrase:** `keystorepwd`
- In General tab, `SSL Certificate Verification` is `OFF`

**API Hit in postman:**

[image: api hit]

- As you could see above screenshot, ERROR something like `Error: error:0900006e:PEM routines:OPENSSL_internal:NO_START_LINE` received in postman.

CURL:

```
curl -vk  GET "https://dev.wso2.com:8243/mutualsslapi/1.0.0" -H "accept: applicaition/json"  --cert "C:\Development_Avecto\Learning\File\dev.wso2.crt" --key "C:\Development_Avecto\Learning\File\devwso2.pem"
```

after executing above curl in cmd, getting below ERROR

```
    * Could not resolve host: GET
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: GET
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8243...
* Connected to dev.wso2.com (127.0.0.1) port 8243 (#1)
* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
* schannel: Failed to import cert file C:\Development_Avecto\Learning\File\dev.wso2.crt, last error is 0x80092002
* Closing connection 1
curl: (58) schannel: Failed to import cert file C:\Development_Avecto\Learning\File\dev.wso2.crt, last error is 0x80092002
```

May I know why this Mutual SSL protected API call is not happening? How can we fix this?

[Reference Link 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p4H_Wv4TZ-w&t=562s)

[Reference link 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FVwoZGTZpQs&t=11s)

Comment: Try the same with curl and see what error you receive.

Comment: @ycr
Added Curl request and the ERROR what i got after executing curl command executed in  cmd. please have a look on edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like an issue with the certificates that you are using.

Try with the following commands to generate private key and public certificate out of it.

**Generated a Key**

```
openssl genrsa -out self.key 2048
```

**Generated the certificate**

```
openssl req -key self.key -new -x509 -days 365 -out self.crt
```

Then test an API configured as below. Note that certificate has been added to the API under Transport level security.
[image]

Then use the key and certificate in the postman as below.

[image]

You will be able to invoke the API. Test whether similar configuration like this works for Mutual SSL.

Comment: Hi @nuwan karunarathna,
Thanks for the response.openssl is not installed , so i tried via java keytool. can't we achieve the same usecase via Java keytool? Isn't that right way? we should generate certificate via openssl only?

Comment: Hi @nuwan karunarathna,
Created .crt,.key file using open ssl command(openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout "C:\path_to_wso2apim_security_folder\privatekey.key" -out "C:\path_to_wso2apim_security_folder\certificate.crt") and attached the same in API and postman as you shown above. Initially got ERROR like sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target" in log file.
Note: after server restart, this starts working fine now

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a postman specific issue. Can you check the options mentioned here[1] to solve the issue? Or can be due to some structure issue in the crt file.

[1] https://community.postman.com/t/error-errorpem-routinesno-start-line/32031

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @nuwan karunarathna,

- I have installed `openssl` in windows machine.
- Created `certificate` and `privatekey` using `openssl` command mentioned [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FVwoZGTZpQs)

`openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout "C:\path_to_wso2apim_security_folder\privatekey.key" -out "C:\path_to_wso2apim_security_folder\certificate.crt"`

- Enabled mutual ssl in Publisher portal and Attached certificate in API level
- Added `certificate, Host` and `private key` in postman setting (certificate tab)
- Restarted WSO2 APIm Server and API Hits are happening now.

[image: API Hit]